# Why does C# Thread.Join returns on first await

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a code like this:

```
var t = new Thread(async () =>
    {
        await DoSomeWorkAsync();
    });
t.Start();
t.Join();


..

public static async Task DoSomeWorkAsync()
{
    var o = await GetSomethingAsync();
    o.StartSomething();
    ..
}
```

I've noticed that the t.Join() returns automatically after the await. I'd like to understand why.

Thanks

Comment: _The_ fundamental characteristic of `async` methods is that such a method will _return_ on reaching the first `await` statement which cannot be completed synchronously. Since a thread exits when its entry point method returns, _that ends the thread_. Any investigation at all into what `async`/`await` does would have revealed that. See duplicates for discussions address this directly and more generally.

Comment: Related: [Is it ok to use “async” with a ThreadStart method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364092/is-it-ok-to-use-async-with-a-threadstart-method)

Answer (score 0):

```
I'd like to understand why
```

Because the constructor you are using has `delegate` with a `void` return type, you will see the same behaviour with other delegates of the same nature, like actions.

```
public delegate void ThreadStart();
```

The compiler would warn you about this. However, in short you are running the *async lambda* task completely unobserved regardless of the thread you started.

FWIW, you should steer away from the `Thread` class altogether and use *Tasks* (unless you have an exceptional use case that would specifically require it).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I thought adding an async lambda will make the thread await.
I tried adding a line after the await and that code never get executed:
var t = new Thread(async () =>
    {
        await DoSomeWorkAsync();
       DoSomethingSync();
    });

I expected DoSomethingSync to be executed at least.

Comment: @0x8000FFFF Yeah there are several things going on here, all of them bad.. In short, don't do that :)

Comment: @0x8000FFFF Also the reason its not running the subsequent methods is because your application is likely ending before it schedules the continuation to the *antecedent* task