# How is the "static *async* Task Main()" started?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to figure out how an async main method is started in C#. To do this I would like to create an example of a new Thread that is the same as the async main thread.

This is how it is done without async:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Main2)
        { IsBackground = false };
        t.Start();
    }

    public static void Main2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Helloooo");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Woooorld");
    }
}
```

If I run the code above, the following is printed:

```
Helloooo
Woooorld
```

You can see that I don't add a `t.Join()` that's because t is a foreground thread. But if try to do the same with async the following happens:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Main2)
        { IsBackground = false };
        t.Start();
    }

    // Can't use "public static async Task main2"
    // because you need to pass in a void method to a new thread
    public static async void Main2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Helloooo");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Woooorld");
    }
}
```

Only

```
Helloooo
```

Is printed, and the program exits, even though the new thread is a foreground thread. Now I understand what is happening here, When the new thread reaches `await Task.Delay(1000);` It starts up a state machine and releases the thread for other things. What I want to know is what I have to change to let my original thread die, and let my new thread take over. I want to understand how the async/await chain gets *started*.

Comment: Why are you using a thread if what you've got is a task? What are you intending to achieve? The proper way to do this is to make `Main2` return `Task` (not `void`) and `await` it in `Main` (which should then also become `async Task`).

Comment: I think you should read more about what async is and how the methods break-up into statemachines.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I want to understand how the async/await chain gets started. Is what is calling ```public static async Task Main``` also calling ```await Main()```, and is the function calling that also using await? How is it started? How can I start my own?

Comment: Note that your title asks something different than your question body: Your title mentions an "static async Task Main()", but none of the methods in your question body returns a `Task`.

Comment: How is it started? Well, either through something like `Task.Run` if you're doing it yourself or the equivalent in the compiler when it sees your `Main` returns a `Task`.

Comment: Related: [Is it ok to use "async" with a ThreadStart method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364092/is-it-ok-to-use-async-with-a-threadstart-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An article about C# 7.1 says:

*"Allow await to be used in an application's Main / entrypoint method by allowing the entrypoint to return Task / Task and be marked async."*

```
public static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task MainAsync()
{
    ... // Main body here
}
```

*"We can remove the need for this boilerplate and make it easier to get started simply by allowing Main itself to be async such that awaits can be used in it."*

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main

As you can see, they don't spin up a separate thread, but "blocking" the current thread until the MainAsync returning task IsCompleted.

Comment: So is it then correct to say that all C# async programs have a minimum of 2 threads, one of them always blocking(assuming somewhere in the main async is called)?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the following combination of factors:

- In a Console application, `SynchronizationContext.Current` not is set.
- If `SynchronizationContext.Current` not is set, await responses (e.g. printing "Woooorld" in your example) are invoked on a ThreadPool thread.
- ThreadPool threads are background threads.