# .NET 6.0 PeriodicTimer in Background Thread 300% cpu

Tags: .net-6.0, cpu-usage, background-thread, periodictimer

```
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

new Thread(async () =>
    {
        try
            {
                while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    ... do some things
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
    })
    {
        IsBackground = true,
    }
.Start();
```

Every 5 minutes I have to do some things in the background thread.
For some reason in some random time I get 300% cpu usage. Something wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI `new Thread` is kind of useless here. Use `Task.Run`.

Comment: Also _"300% CPU"_ is an interesting claim, how have you measured this?

Comment: @GuruStron how about this? https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskrun-for-long-running-work-that-blocks-the-thread

Comment: `await timer` - your code does not block the thread.

Comment: The problem with `Thread` is the same as one which is mentioned in _"Don't use TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning with async code as this will create a new thread which will be destroyed after first await."_.

Comment: I doubt that this will actually fix your problems though. I would argue that they are not present in the provided code. It is either in `... do some things` on in the code doing `new Thread`.

Answer (score -1):

> Something wrong with my code?

Yes, there is something wrong with this code, but fixing it will not solve the CPU over-utilization problem. The wrong thing is that you pass an asynchronous delegate to the `Thread` constructor. The `Thread` class does not expect an `async` delegate in the constructor, so the delegate is `async void`, which is [something to avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). You can learn why this is pointless from the answer in this question:

- [Is it ok to use "async" with a ThreadStart method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364092/is-it-ok-to-use-async-with-a-threadstart-method)

You can fix this by replacing the `new Thread(async () =>` with `Task.Run(async () =>`. The `Task.Run` method understands async delegates, and will give you back a `Task` that you can later `await`, or query for its completion and potential [`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception). In case you want to keep the existing `async void` semantics, meaning that in case of an unhandled exception you want your program to crash, then replace the `new Thread(async () =>` with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async _ =>`.

As for the reason for the CPU spikes, it is hidden in the `... do some things` code. We don't know what this code does, so we can't help you fix it.