# Problem with thread synchronisation in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, race-condition

I am creating a Discord bot in C# that displays a list of users in a queue. The list is updated every 30 seconds.

I have two threads, the main thread and the one I created. In the main thread, I have bound a button press event handler on which an asynchronous method is bound. And in the thread I created, I have bound an asynchronous queue update method which has a Delay of 30 seconds and should be executed every 30 seconds. The problem is that both threads are interacting with the same resource (static dictionary), which can lead to incorrect data changes.

I wanted to use the lock construct, but I think then the thread updating the queue would have to wait a long time to be let into the lock block, which means that the queue would not be updated every 30 seconds.

Please help me solve this problem, I am new to programming!

```
private async void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  new Thread(async () =>
  {
    while (true)
    {
        await UpdateQueue();
        await Task.Delay(30000);
    }
  }).Start();

  channel = await discord.GetChannelAsync(queueChannelID);

  discord.ComponentInteractionCreated += Discord_ButtonIsPressed;

  await discord.ConnectAsync();

  await Task.Delay(-1);
}

private async Task UpdateQueue()
{
  queue.Add("test", "test"); // this is where new items are added to the queue from the database
  blackList.Add("test", "test"); // this is where new items are added to the blacklist from the database

  DiscordMessage message = await channel.GetMessageAsync(messageID);

  await message.ModifyAsync(queue["test"]); // this is where the queue is sent to the Discord channel
}

private async Task Discord_ButtonIsPressed(DiscordClient sender, DSharpPlus.EventArgs.ComponentInteractionCreateEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Interaction.Data.CustomId == "queue")
  {
     DiscordMessageBuilder message = new();

     DiscordEmbedBuilder embed = new();
     embed.WithTitle("Queue");
     embed.AddField("firstUser", queue["test"]);

     message.AddEmbed(embed);

     await args.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource, new DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder(message));
  }

  // there will be logic to handle the fact that a person has made more than 50 requests in 30 seconds
  blackList.Add("test", args.User.Id.ToString());
}
```

Comment: We, sadly, cannot see your IDE. Please provide the code that is causing an issue so we can help you.

Comment: We can't guess what the code is doing. C# has classes and keywords that eliminate most synchronization issues. There's no asynchronous queue but types like Channel or ActionBlock offer far more features. On the other hand `a Delay of 30 seconds and should be executed every 30 seconds.` isn't about asynchronous execution at all, it's about scheduled jobs. `static dictionary), which can lead to incorrect data changes` you can avoid that if you use a `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: What's the actual problem you want to solve? Explain the logic, not how you think it can be implemented.

Comment: As mentioned, we need to see your code to know your approach, but if your concern is the lock causing a long delay in it's queue, you should only lock when modifying the shared object, don't include unnecessary code in the lock.  As for exactly 30 seconds, it sounds as if you are targeting precision timing, which unfortunately means you are in the wrong programming language.  In C# timed execution is unreliable due to the runtime.  Any thread can be paused by the garbage collector.  It doesn't matter which timer you are using, there is no guarantee it will execute on time.

Comment: Without anything to really work with i took away from your question that you have concurrent access on a dictionary and a problem with that. There is a ConcurrentDictionary in the framework that might help to a certain extent . You seems to call the Dictionary a queue here that reads problematic to me but hopefully you know what you are doing.

Comment: Apologies, added the code!

Comment: As a side note, initializing a `Thread` with an `async` delegate [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364092/is-it-ok-to-use-async-with-a-threadstart-method "Is it ok to use "async" with a ThreadStart method?"). The delegate is `async void`, which is [something to avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming - Avoid Async Void").

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `SemaphoreSlim` would ensure that only one thread can execute the critical section within `UpdateQueue` and `Discord_ButtonIsPressed` at a time.

```
// Semaphore with 1 initial permit & max 1 permit    
private SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1); 

private async void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(); // wait for permit
            try
            {
                await UpdateQueue();
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphoreSlim.Release(); // release
            }

            await Task.Delay(30000);
        }
    }).Start();

    channel = await discord.GetChannelAsync(queueChannelID);

    discord.ComponentInteractionCreated += Discord_ButtonIsPressed;

    await discord.ConnectAsync();

    await Task.Delay(-1);
}

private async Task UpdateQueue()
{
    queue.Add("test", "test");
    blackList.Add("test", "test");

    DiscordMessage message = await channel.GetMessageAsync(messageID);

    await message.ModifyAsync(queue["test"]);
}

private async Task Discord_ButtonIsPressed(DiscordClient sender, DSharpPlus.EventArgs.ComponentInteractionCreateEventArgs args)
{
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(); // wait for a permit
    try
    {
        if (args.Interaction.Data.CustomId == "queue")
        {
            DiscordMessageBuilder message = new();

            DiscordEmbedBuilder embed = new();
            embed.WithTitle("Queue");
            embed.AddField("firstUser", queue["test"]);

            message.AddEmbed(embed);

            await args.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource, new DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder(message));
        }

        blackList.Add("test", args.User.Id.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release(); // release permit
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please explain how this implementation differs from the lock design?

Comment: `Lock` can only be used for synchronous code. You wouldn't be able to use `await` inside the lock of `Discord_ButtonisPressed` for example. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await.

Comment: You might want to add proper exception handling if you need to consume exceptions.

Comment: Thank you. And also, will there be a problem that I wrote about? `but I think then the thread updating the queue would have to wait a long time to be let into the lock block, which means that the queue would not be updated every 30 seconds`

Comment: Is the resource you need to lock blackList only or the queue also?

Comment: and the queue and the blackList